# The mirror that apt-get is trying to use is down

Tags: apt, osmc, source.list

I'm living in China and am working on getting OSMC up and going. However, when trying to `apt-get install` anything, it keeps trying to use `mirrors.zju.edu.cn`, which is down.

I know I can edit `sources.list`, but what do I put? Is there a way to "exclude" certain mirror locations?

Answer (score 1):

I found the list of [mirrors for Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors) and found one that was working. I edited my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file from:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://apt.osmc.tv jessie main
```

to:

```
# deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://apt.osmc.tv jessie main
```

That did the trick. I'm guessing that this probably isn't smart for long term solutions, but worked temporarily.